How do I delete all the lines that match and one after each of them?
I have a large file and a list of my specific strings. The output should not contain my specific lines and one more after each of them. 2 consecutive matches are impossible due to structure of file that i want to filter. For example,
Specific lines:
'ggg'
'sss'

Input:
'ggg'
'123'
'rrr'
'321'
'sss'
'666'

Output:
'rrr'
'321'

Simple grep -v -A 1 does not work

are all strings always wrapped in single quotes? do you want exact matches or are substring matches acceptable, eg, should 'rrr' match on 'rrrrr'?  do you want exact line matches or are substring matches acceptable, eg, should 'rrr' match on a single line that looks like 'aaa' 'rrr' 'ggg'?

No, it is just an example, strings do not wrapped in quotes. I need only exact matches, so 'rrr' mathes exact 'rrr'

What if, in the second file, you have 2 consecutive lines that match a line of first file? Do you just skip them or do you also skip the next one? Example: line 1: 'ggg', line 2: sss, line 3: 123, do you skip 123 or not?

2 consecutive mathes are impossible due to structure of file that i want to filter. I have a line with 'id' then a line with information about this item, then repeat

@ЖеняГончаров OK, thanks. Please edit your question and add this important piece of information such that future readers have all they need to understand.

This question has been closed as duplicate of another question that is rather different (in the other question there is only one file, we print a line or not based on the next line in the unique file, ...) This one may be a duplicate, but not of the cited question. I vote to reopen.

Assumptions:

we are looking for exact line matches, to include white space, punctuation marks and quotes
matches can occur on consecutive lines in which case we ignore all matches plus the next non-matching line (NOTE: OP has added a comment stating consecutive line matches are not possible; see end of answer for a simplified awk script)

General approach:

if we find a matching line then we ignore the current line and set a flag to ignore the next line
if the flag is set we ignore the current line and clear the flag
otherwise we print the current line

Sample input file:
$ cat input
'ggg'                       # match/ignore and 
'123'                       # ignore
'rrr'
'321'
'sss'                       # match/ignore and 
'666'                       # ignore
'aaa' 'ggg' 'xxx'
'12345'
'xxx'                       # match/ignore and
'xxx'                       # match/ignore and
98352                       # ignore
'xyz'
hello world

Sample set of lines to match on (and ignore):
$ cat lines
'ggg'              # will not match on the line: 'aaa' 'ggg' 'xxx'
'sss'
rrr                # will not match on 'rrr' because of the missing quotes
'xxx'              # will match on consecutive lines and skip the next non-matching line

NOTE: comments do not exist in files
One awk idea:
awk '
#### 1st file:

FNR==NR { a[$0];  next }       # save line as index in array a[]

#### 2nd file:

$0 in a { skip=1; next }       # if line is an index in array then set the "skip" flag and ignore this line

skip    { skip=0; next }       # if flag is set then clear flag and ignore this line

1                              # otherwise print current line
' lines input

######
# or as a one-liner

awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} $0 in a {skip=1;next} skip {skip=0;next} 1' lines input

This generates:
'rrr'
'321'
'aaa' 'ggg' 'xxx'
'12345'
'xyz'
hello world

NOTE: if assumptions are wrong and/or this does not work for OP's actual files then we'll need the question updated with a more representative set of data

OP has added a comment stating consecutive line matches cannot occur.  This allows us to simplify the code a bit:
awk '
FNR==NR { a[$0];   next }       # 1st file: save line as index in array a[]
$0 in a { getline; next }       # 2nd file: if line is an index in array then get next line (and ignore) then skip to next input line otherwise ...
1                               # print current line
' lines input

######
# or as a one-liner

awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} $0 in a {getline;next} 1' lines input

If we remove one of the 'xxx' lines from the input file this will generate:
'rrr'
'321'
'aaa' 'ggg' 'xxx'
'12345'
'xyz'
hello world


The following assumes that there cannot be two consecutive matching lines in the second file.
With any POSIX awk you can easily implement a state machine to do this while reading the second file:
awk 'FNR == NR {a[$0]; next}
     skip == 1 {skip = 0; next}
     $0 in a   {skip = 1; next}
               {skip = 0; print}' file1 file2

When parsing the first file (FNR == NR) we store the lines in associative array a and move to next line (next). When parsing the second file we are either in skip == 1 or skip == 0 states. The initial state is skip == 0 and the behavior of the state machine is:

If we are in the skip == 1 state, set state to skip == 0 and move to next line without printing the current one (it is a line following a matching one).
Else, if the current line matches one from first file, set state to skip == 1 and move to next line without printing the current one (it is a matching one).
Else, set state to skip == 0 and print current line (it is not a matching one and not a line following a matching one).


Using any awk:
$ awk 'NR==FNR{lines[$0]; next} $0 in lines{c=2} !(c&&c--)' lines input
'rrr'
'321'

If you want to skip 15 lines instead of 2, change 2 to 15.
See also Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern for similar idioms.

Here is the awk script:
function check(line) { return \
line != "'ggg'" && \
line != "'sss'"
}
check($0) && check(prev) {print $0}
{prev = $0}

And also the Perl script:
open(FH, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die;
while(<FH>){
    push @spec, $_;
}
close(FH);
open(FH, '<', $ARGV[1]) or die;
while($line = <FH>){
    if (not (grep /$line/, @spec) and (length $prev <= 0 or not (grep /$prev/, @spec))) {
        print $line;
    }
    $prev = $line;
}
close(FH);

It takes 2 command line arguments: a file with specific strings and an input file.

the match strings ('ggg' and 'sss') need to be read from a file, not hardcoded in the script

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's#.*#/^&$/ba#' lines | sed -f - -e 'b;:a;N;d' file

Use the lines file to generate a sed input file of regexs for each line in the lines input.
Pass the regexs via pipe to sed invocation that does nothing if the regexs do not match. Otherwise, append the next line and delete both the matching and the next line.
